# How to convert multiple data sources into a predefined data structure in python?

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am creating a parser that takes data from multiple sources with multiple data schema and then converts them to a standardized structured schema.

For example, I have 2 sources of data:

Source 1:

```json
{
  "students: [{
     "id": 129939,
     "name": "Alice",
     "gender": "female",
  }]
}
```

Source 2:

```json
{
  "students: [{
     "id": 129939,
     "fullname": "Alice",
     "sex": "female",
  }]
}
```

Both sources of data can be converted into standardized structured data that I already defined:

```py
class Student:
   id: int
   name: str
   gender: str
```

Do you know is there any existing library that supports defines the schema for each input data source and then allows to map each field of the input source to the wanted data structure?

For example, it can be a mapper like this:

```py
class Input1toStudentMapper:
   id -> Student.id
   name -> Student.name
   gender -> Student.gender
```

```py
class Input2toStudentMapper:
   id -> Student.id
   fullname -> Student.name
   sex -> Student.gender
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you pick a single structure and create a parser dor it, then you can use regex to edit the jsons. for example read the json, use re.sub to replace "fullname" to "name" and then parse

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any library, but for the problem you are describing - you can probably code the logic into the `__init__` of the class itself -

```
class Student:
    name_field_variations = ['name', 'fullname']
    sex_field_variations = ['gender', 'sex']
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs['id']
        _name_field = set(kwargs.keys()) & set(Student.name_field_variations)
        self.name = kwargs[_name_field.pop()]
        _sex_field = set(kwargs.keys()) & set(Student.sex_field_variations)
        self.gender = kwargs[_sex_field.pop()]

print(js1) # {'students': [{'id': 129939, 'name': 'Alice', 'gender': 'female'}]}
print(js2) # {'students': [{'id': 129939, 'fullname': 'Alice', 'sex': 'female'}]}
s1 = Student(**js1['students'][0])
s2 = Student(**js2['students'][0])
print(s1.gender) # female
print(s2.gender) # female
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library for this. It plays well with the built in [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module in Python. It supports multiple aliases (or key mappings) for each field, as well as a one-way alias which we might want in this case - ex. if we want to allow an additional mapping of `fullname` to the `name` field, but serialize using the default key `name`.

In the below example I also added a `__future__` import which is supported in Python 3.7 or higher. This is mainly to support the use of forward references; without this future import, we will need to explicitly define forward references, for ex. like `List['Student']`.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

from dataclass_wizard import json_key
from typing_extensions import Annotated


@dataclass
class Container:
    students: List[Student]


@dataclass
class Student:
    id: int
    name: Annotated[str, json_key('fullname')]
    gender: Annotated[str, json_key('sex')]
```

In the annotation above, declaring it like `json_key('fullname')` is a shorthand for `json_key('name', 'fullname', all=True)`, which is also how multiple aliases could be mapped to a field.

Note that if you only plan to support Python 3.9 or above, you can make the below changes:

- Import `Annotated` from the `typing` module instead
- Remove the `from typing import List` import and define the annotation like `list[Student]`

Here is sample usage for testing out the above code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from dataclass_wizard import asdict, fromdict, fromlist

    source_1 = {
        "students": [{
            "id": 129939,
            "name": "Alice",
            "gender": "female",
        }]
    }

    source_2 = {
        "students": [{
            "id": 129940,
            "fullname": "Johnny",
            "sex": "male",
        }]
    }

    c1 = fromdict(Container, source_1)
    print(c1)
    # Container(students=[Student(id=129939, name='Alice', gender='female')])

    c2 = fromdict(Container, source_2)
    print(c2)
    # Container(students=[Student(id=129940, name='Johnny', gender='male')])

    # alternatively, if you just need a list of the `Student` instances:
    students = fromlist(Student, source_1['students'])
    print(students)
    # [Student(id=129939, name='Alice', gender='female')]

    # assert we get the same data when serializing the Container instance as a
    # Python dict object.
    serialized_dict = asdict(c1)
    assert serialized_dict == source_1
```